# ng-controller not rendering data to browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular JS and I am facing some issues in the ng-controller which is not sending values to the browser screen. I am using angular 1.5.8. How can I get this code to display values.Attached is my output as well 
[image]
Here is my code :
script.js

```
(function () {
var gem = {
    name: "Dodecahedron",
    price: 2.95,
    description: "great stone"
};
var app = angular.module('store', []);
app.controller('StoreController', function () {
    this.product = gem;
});
})();
```

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="store">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"       href="bootstrap/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
</head>
<body >
{{"Hello" + "Angular"}}
<br />
Here is Where our gem information will be displayed through the controller.

<div ng-controller="StoreController">
    {{"Hello" + "Angular"}}
    <h1>Product name : {{StoreController.product.name}}</h1>
    <h2>Produce Price : {{StoreController.product.price}}</h2>
    <p>Product Description : {{StoreController.product.description}}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $scope variable inside controller

```
app.controller('StoreController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.product = gem;
});
```

in html you can access $scope variables directly like this

```html
<div ng-controller="StoreController">
    {{"Hello" + "Angular"}}
    <h1>Product name : {{product.name}}</h1>
    <h2>Produce Price : {{product.price}}</h2>
    <p>Product Description : {{product.description}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use $scope variable

```
app.controller('StoreController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.product = gem;
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/p9j5FdlxKi6BZDURN0qC?p=preview)

else you can use the Controller as syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing **"StoreController as StoreController"**.

```
<div ng-controller="StoreController as StoreController">
    {{"Hello" + "Angular"}}
    <h1>Product name : {{StoreController.product.name}}</h1>
    <h2>Produce Price : {{StoreController.product.price}}</h2>
    <p>Product Description : {{StoreController.product.description}}</p>
</div>
```

Working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/lnR2GdB7j9sPs3QQC4Ef?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use `$scope`, you can use `controller as` systax.

```
<div ng-controller="StoreController as ctrl">
    {{"Hello" + "Angular"}}
    <h1>Product name : {{ctrl.product.name}}</h1>
    <h2>Produce Price : {{ctrl.product.price}}</h2>
    <p>Product Description : {{product.description}}</p>
</div>
```